# How to reverse the `unstack` method of a `DataFrame` in `pandas` back to original object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot-table

I want to convert a symmetric similarity matrix (`pd.DataFrame`) into an unstacked `pd.Series` with a `pd.MultiIndex` and then back into a `pd.DataFrame`

Here is the code to get the symmetric `pd.DataFrame` and my attempt to reverse the operation.

Am I supposed to use `pivot`? I want to end up with another `pd.DataFrame` called `df_sqr_revert` that is the same as the original `df_sqr`.

**Does anyone have any idea how to reverse this operation?**

```
data = {'sepal_length': {'sepal_length': 1.0, 'sepal_width': 0.44531537502467533, 'petal_length': 0.935877078652436, 'petal_width': 0.9089768166845817}, 'sepal_width': {'sepal_length': 0.44531537502467533, 'sepal_width': 1.0, 'petal_length': 0.2897419517994226, 'petal_width': 0.32172795519309727}, 'petal_length': {'sepal_length': 0.935877078652436, 'sepal_width': 0.2897419517994226, 'petal_length': 1.0, 'petal_width': 0.9813785485254833}, 'petal_width': {'sepal_length': 0.9089768166845817, 'sepal_width': 0.32172795519309727, 'petal_length': 0.9813785485254833, 'petal_width': 1.0}}

df_sqr = pd.DataFrame(data)
#               petal_length  petal_width  sepal_length  sepal_width
# petal_length      1.000000     0.981379      0.935877     0.289742
# petal_width       0.981379     1.000000      0.908977     0.321728
# sepal_length      0.935877     0.908977      1.000000     0.445315
# sepal_width       0.289742     0.321728      0.445315     1.000000
Se_vertical = df_sqr.unstack()
# petal_length  petal_length    1.000000
#               petal_width     0.981379
#               sepal_length    0.935877
#               sepal_width     0.289742
# petal_width   petal_length    0.981379
#               petal_width     1.000000
#               sepal_length    0.908977
#               sepal_width     0.321728
# sepal_length  petal_length    0.935877
#               petal_width     0.908977
#               sepal_length    1.000000
#               sepal_width     0.445315
# sepal_width   petal_length    0.289742
#               petal_width     0.321728
#               sepal_length    0.445315
#               sepal_width     1.000000
# dtype: float64

# df_sqr_revert = Se_vertical.stack()
# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'stack'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paradoxically, what you want here is a second unstack call:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
              sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width
petal_length      0.935877     0.289742      1.000000     0.981379
petal_width       0.908977     0.321728      0.981379     1.000000
sepal_length      1.000000     0.445315      0.935877     0.908977
sepal_width       0.445315     1.000000      0.289742     0.321728


In [13]: df_sqr.unstack().unstack()
Out[13]: 
              petal_length  petal_width  sepal_length  sepal_width
sepal_length      0.935877     0.908977      1.000000     0.445315
sepal_width       0.289742     0.321728      0.445315     1.000000
petal_length      1.000000     0.981379      0.935877     0.289742
petal_width       0.981379     1.000000      0.908977     0.321728
```

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) mentions that unstack in the case of a series equals pivot, like you suspected in your question.

---

## Bonus

Just because I was curious, the difference between stack and unstack becomes more apparent when we prefix the columns and index labels:

```
In [17]: df.columns  = [f'columns_{i}' for i in df.columns]

In [18]: df.index  = [f'index_{i}' for i in df.index]
```

`.stack()` puts the row-index as the left-most level of the multi-index:

```
In [20]: df.stack()
Out[20]: 
index_petal_length  columns_sepal_length    0.935877
                    columns_sepal_width     0.289742
                    columns_petal_length    1.000000
                    columns_petal_width     0.981379
index_petal_width   columns_sepal_length    0.908977
                    columns_sepal_width     0.321728
                    columns_petal_length    0.981379
                    columns_petal_width     1.000000
index_sepal_length  columns_sepal_length    1.000000
                    columns_sepal_width     0.445315
                    columns_petal_length    0.935877
                    columns_petal_width     0.908977
index_sepal_width   columns_sepal_length    0.445315
                    columns_sepal_width     1.000000
                    columns_petal_length    0.289742
                    columns_petal_width     0.321728
dtype: float64
```

`.unstack()` puts the column index as the left-most level of the multi-index:

```
In [21]: df.unstack()
Out[21]: 
columns_sepal_length  index_petal_length    0.935877
                      index_petal_width     0.908977
                      index_sepal_length    1.000000
                      index_sepal_width     0.445315
columns_sepal_width   index_petal_length    0.289742
                      index_petal_width     0.321728
                      index_sepal_length    0.445315
                      index_sepal_width     1.000000
columns_petal_length  index_petal_length    1.000000
                      index_petal_width     0.981379
                      index_sepal_length    0.935877
                      index_sepal_width     0.289742
columns_petal_width   index_petal_length    0.981379
                      index_petal_width     1.000000
                      index_sepal_length    0.908977
                      index_sepal_width     0.321728
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Haha, glad it helped!

Comment: Added some more info out of curiosity because honestly I was just found this through trial and error - TIL.

Comment: Isn't `stack` the inverse of `unstack`? So `df.stack().unstack()` is just `df` in pandas 1.4.2. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-stacking